# Postgresql server cant connect

Tags: postgresql, server, database-connection

I apologize in advance for my english. I have install postgresql 14.5 and create database and set postgresql.conf to

`listen_addresses = '*'`

pg_hba.conf to

```
host    all             all              0.0.0.0/0                       md5
host    all             all              ::/0                            md5
```

and add rule for
`port 5432`.
When i connecting from other pc in same network everything works fine, but problem starts when i try to connect db from other network.
Server return timeout. Any ideas :)?

Comment: Network problem.

Comment: Do you have firewall?
The DB is accessible locally, maybe you need to whitelist the IP from the other network

Comment: antyvirus is turned off. How to configure whitelist?